# My vim keeps showing errors regarding diff and gzip

Tags: unix, vim, csh

I was trying to diff two files with gvimdiff a.txt and b.txt and vim shows

> E97:Cannot Create diffs

and when i tried opening a .gz file it shows

> Error detected while processing function gzip#read: line   44: Error:
> Could not read uncompressed file
> [image]

Just to make sure i did not mess up my .vimrc,.cshrc and .alias file i reverted back to empty .vimrc and .vim folder in my home directory, similarly i removed all my additions in .cshrc and .alias.

This issue is bugging me since a day and  it was fine few hours before.
Is there a way that i can get this resolved without installing any files with sudo?
Please suggest some changes to get back to original.

vim used is vim7.4

Edit:
The issue keeps coming back again.
to check some vim help, I tried `:help E97` and it shows the same error
[image]

Is the colorcheme file creating a issue here?
I am using solarized as color scheme picked up from github.

Comment: Are you able to uncompress the file?

Comment: Do any external commands work? For example, `:!uname` and `:echo system(`uname`).

Comment: @IngoKarkat 
`:!uname` returns linux , but the `echo system(uname`)` returns E116: Invalid arguments for function system( uname`)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes,I'm able to uncompress.

Comment: Ah, typo, I mean `:echo system('uname')`. But I guess that will work as well.

Comment: yes, this returns Linux.

Comment: @IngoKarkat The issue gets resolved after restarting and returns after sometime.